# Set up workflow connection MySQL ODBC

Tags: informatica-powercenter

**How do I set up a connection using MySQL ODBC Connector 5.3 within the Informatica Powercenter Workflow Manager?**

Under Connections -> Relational, I can create a new ODBC connection, but the only place I can specify something is within the Connect String, and it is not as obvious what to put in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect string = ODBC DSN Name

Data source must be defined in ODBC Data Source Administator in windows' Administrative Tools